# Unity container resolve constructor with no parameter

Tags: c#, constructor, .net-4.0, unity-container

One of my class has 2 constructors:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo() { }

    public Foo(string bar) { }
}
```

When I am resolving this from unity, I get an exception because it looks for the `string bar` parameter. But I want the unity to instantiate this class using the constructor with no parameter. How can I achieve this?

I am using the `LoadConfiguration` method to register the types from the configuration file.

Unity Container Configuration:

```
container.LoadConfiguration("containerName");
```

Config File:

```
<unity xmlns="">
  <typeAliases>
    <typeAlias alias="string" type="System.String, mscorlib" />
    <typeAlias alias="singleton" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ContainerControlledLifetimeManager, Microsoft.Practices.Unity" />
  </typeAliases>
  <containers>
    <container name="containerName">
      <types>
        <type type="IFoo, Assembly"
              mapTo="Foo, Assembly" />
        ...
      </types>
    </container>
  </containers>
</unity>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `[InjectionConstructor]` attribute over your constructor specifies which constructor should be used while resolving service

  ```
  public class Foo  : IFoo
  {
     [InjectionConstructor]
     public Foo() { }

     public Foo(string bar) { }
  }
  ```

this approach makes you class coupled to Unity, your class becomes less reusable *(imagine that you need to use `Foo` in different scenario where you need to use another constructor)* and this way is not recommended , read more about [this here](http://codebetter.com/davidhayden/2008/10/28/specifying-injection-constructor-using-unity-fluent-interface-for-loose-coupling-and-poco/)

- Better way is to use API and register you class as follows

  ```
  container.RegisterType<IFoo>(new Foo());
  ```

Here, you explicitly define how you want your dependency to be resolved.

- Alternatively you can use `Xml` Config file, namely specify `<contructor>` element inside `<register>` element

*Notice that we do not specify `<params>` child element inside `<constructor>` element*

> If no `<param>` child elements are present, it indicates that the zero-argument constructor should be called

See more about `Xml` schema [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660914(v=pandp.20).aspx#config_constructor)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try the last one.

Comment: @Kael Glad if helped